# Sorting a list containing lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have an algorithm that generates a list containing an unknown number of sublists, with each sublist having an unknown number of string elements as well as one floating point number. I need these sublists sorted inside of the main list according to this float. Also, the order of the strings in the sublists are not be be rearranged.

I currently have this running through a chunk of code (linked below) that sorts it using a dict. I am getting KeyErrors as you can see. I haven't worked with dicts before, so im not sure where to go from here. If there is a better way then a dict im open to that too. http://ideone.com/wr8UA

The floats are not sequential, im not sure how big of a deal this is using the method i have. Meaning, numbers will occasionally be skipped (in the example list in Ideone they are 1.0, 2.0, 4.0; skipping 3.0 to simulate this situation at runtime). They also arent in any specific location in the sublists, hence all the for loops searching for them.

Hopefully this is clear, i tried asking it before and got downvotes instead of questions about what was confusing to people. Let me know if something is amiss. Thanks everyone!

Edit: Code in the body as requested:

```
listed = [ ["1 NWZ", "1 RWZ", "2 NWZ", "2 RWZ", "1E HZ", "1W HZ", "1-2EHZ", 2.0, "2W HZ"],
["1 NWZ", "1W HZ", "3E FZ", "SNOK", "POK", 3.0, "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", "2W HZ"],
["1 BW", "1AW AS", "3E FZ", "1BWAK", "POK", "TESTK", "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", 1.0]] 

dictionary={}
for sub_list in listed:
    for value in sub_list:
        if isinstance(value,float):
            dictionary[str(value)]=sub_list
        else:
            pass
ordered_list=[]
    for i in range(1,len(listed)+1):
    if dictionary[str(i)]:
        ordered_list.append(dictionary[str(i)])

for sub_list in ordered_list:
    print sub_list
```

Comment: put the code inside the question, it's not so long!

Comment: @heltonbiker sure, but i'll leave the link too since it has the errors and line numbers listed.

Comment: Most of the answers provided will operate in something like n^2 * log(n) time if you use them as is.  You should optimize to make sure your float occurs first in the sublists and take the shortcut of using the first element so as not to have to search the list for it each time.

Comment: @Wug true, im sure theres a way to do that in the other algorithm. But would this efficency be relevant for small series of data? As it stands, each sublist will probably be no more then 50 values (rarely that high), and there will be less then 15 sublists. Previous algorithm efficiency courses i've had lead me to believe that for small amounts of data like this i'd only be saving milliseconds, even if the big-O efficiency is way better

Comment: For small data sets it's probably irrelevant.  For anything containing maybe a hundred lists of a hundred elements, you would probably see noticable differences.

Comment: Mkay thats what i thought, thanks for clarifying though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`sort` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) has a handy `key` keyword argument, that let's you specify a function to call to determine on what information a list should be sorted.

Sorting your lists is as easy as writing a function that returns the float value contained in each sub list:

```
def sortOnFloat(sublist):
    return [v for v in sublist if isinstance(v, float)]
```

Note that I simply return a `list` of all the float values; much easier than having to return just one. This'll work even if there are 0 float values in the sublist.

Sort your list like this:

```
listed.sort(key=sortOnFloat)
```

I've cloned your example and updated it with the above method: http://ideone.com/u8ufK

Output generated:

```
['1 BW', '1AW AS', '3E FZ', '1BWAK', 'POK', 'TESTK', '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', 1.0]
['1 NWZ', '1 RWZ', '2 NWZ', '2 RWZ', '1E HZ', '1W HZ', '1-2EHZ', 2.0, '2W HZ']
['1 NWZ', '1W HZ', '3E FZ', 'SNOK', 'POK', 3.0, '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', '2W HZ']
```

Note that the `.sort()` method sorts the list in-place. You can also use the [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) to generate a new list that has been sorted; it takes the same argument:

```
orderedlist = sorted(listed, key=sortOnFloat)
```

but note that in-place sorting is always faster.

Comment: Awesome, im gonna test this out and get back to you afterwards. Also thanks for the simple differentiation between sort and sorted, i never knew there was a difference!

Comment: Works great! Thanks a bunch! This is way simpler then looping all around a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Create a function to extract the key on which you want to sort, and call [sorted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

```
listed = [ ["1 NWZ", "1 RWZ", "2 NWZ", "2 RWZ", "1E HZ", "1W HZ", "1-2EHZ", 2.0, "2W HZ"],
["1 NWZ", "1W HZ", "3E FZ", "SNOK", "POK", 3.0, "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", "2W HZ"],
["1 BW", "1AW AS", "3E FZ", "1BWAK", "POK", "TESTK", "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", 1.0]] 

def get_key(l):
    return next(e for e in l if type(e) is float)

print sorted(listed, key=get_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link could help you, which gives the method of implementing customized sorting in almost every language.

[Sort using a custom comparator](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator#Python)

Comment: This is an awesome link, im sure i'll use this in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because the numbers in the lists are floats, but you look for keys using integers:

```
listed = [ ["1 NWZ", "1 RWZ", "2 NWZ", "2 RWZ", "1E HZ", "1W HZ", "1-2EHZ", 2.0, "2W HZ"],
["1 NWZ", "1W HZ", "3E FZ", "SNOK", "POK", 3.0, "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", "2W HZ"],
["1 BW", "1AW AS", "3E FZ", "1BWAK", "POK", "TESTK", "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", 1.0]]

dictionary={}
for sub_list in listed:
    for value in sub_list:
        if isinstance(value,float):  #### you look for floats
            dictionary[str(value)]=sub_list   ### the key is created as string
        else:
            pass
ordered_list=[]
for i in range(1,len(listed)+1):   ### this is a range of INTS!!!!
    if dictionary[str(i)]:
        ordered_list.append(dictionary[str(i)])  #### str(i) is '1', not '1.0' 

for sub_list in ordered_list:
    print sub_list
```

I can only think this is not good code. In the first place, there shouldn't be strings and numbers mixed inside the same lists. If you create that lists, I suggest you to use a dict, like for example this:

```
listitem = {'number': 2.0, 'strings': ['1 NHZ', '1 RWZ', 'TESTK']}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> listed = [ ["1 NWZ", "1 RWZ", "2 NWZ", "2 RWZ", "1E HZ", "1W HZ", "1-2EHZ", 2.0, "2W HZ"],
["1 NWZ", "1W HZ", "3E FZ", "SNOK", "POK", 3.0, "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", "2W HZ"],
["1 BW", "1AW AS", "3E FZ", "1BWAK", "POK", "TESTK", "1-2EHZ", "2E AK", 1.0]]
>>> listed
[['1 NWZ', '1 RWZ', '2 NWZ', '2 RWZ', '1E HZ', '1W HZ', '1-2EHZ', 2.0, '2W HZ'], ['1 NWZ', '1W HZ', '3E FZ', 'SNOK', 'POK', 3.0, '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', '2W HZ'], ['1 BW', '1AW AS', '3E FZ', '1BWAK', 'POK', 'TESTK', '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', 1.0]]
>>> dictionary ={}
>>> for index,sub_list in enumerate(listed):
    for value in sub_list:
        if isinstance(value,float):
            dictionary[value]=index
        else:
            pass


>>> dictionary
{1.0: 2, 2.0: 0, 3.0: 1}
>>> it = sorted(dictionary.items())
>>> it
[(1.0, 2), (2.0, 0), (3.0, 1)]
>>> ordered_list = []
>>> for item in it:
    ordered_list.append(listed[item[1]])


>>> ordered_list
[['1 BW', '1AW AS', '3E FZ', '1BWAK', 'POK', 'TESTK', '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', 1.0], ['1 NWZ', '1 RWZ', '2 NWZ', '2 RWZ', '1E HZ', '1W HZ', '1-2EHZ', 2.0, '2W HZ'], ['1 NWZ', '1W HZ', '3E FZ', 'SNOK', 'POK', 3.0, '1-2EHZ', '2E AK', '2W HZ']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes because there is no '1' element in your code. It is actually '1.0' (since it is a float), doing this would make the code work:

```
for i in range(1,len(listed)+1):
    if dictionary[str(float(i))]:
        ordered_list.append(dictionary[str(float(i))])
```

However, this is far from being a good way to do what you are trying to do in my opinion and many people gave good advices for alternatives.